# Proving that $(1+\frac{x}{n})^n\to e^x$?

Tags: calculus, limits

> Prove that for all $x\in \mathbb{Z}$ the sequence $(1+\frac{x}{n})^n$ is converging and it's limit is $e^x$.

I'm not even sure how to start this one. How can I even open $(1+\frac{x}{n})$ to something I can work with? I do know $\lim(1+\frac{1}{n})^n=e$, but not sure how to get from one to the other...

Comment: Do you know the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=e\;?$$

Comment: Yeah I do. Though I mentioned it, my bad :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT: Write

$$\left(1+\frac{x}n\right)^n=\left(\left(1+\frac{x}n\right)^{n/x}\right)^x?$$

and substitute $u=\dfrac{x}n$.

Comment: hmm that was simple enough. Thank you!

Comment: @Nescio: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You should know (sometimes by definition) that $(1+\frac1n)^n\to e$.
Consider the case $x\ne0$ (with $x=0$ being trivial).Then clearly $(1+\frac1n)^{nx}\to e^x$.
This already shows $(1+\frac xn)^{n}\to e^x$ at least for the subsequence of naturals $n$ where $n$ is a multiple of $x$.
For the general case, investigate the difference between $(1+\frac xn)^{n}$ and $(1+\frac 1m)^{mx}$, where $m$ is a multuple of $x$ and $m\approx \frac nx$.